# can servlet-name be different in <servlet> and <servlet-mapping>?

Tags: java, xml, servlets

Is this web.xml valid?

can servlet-name be different in servlet and servlet-mapping ?

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Levensthein Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Levensthein</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Levensthein</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot.

The `servlet-name` elements **must** match at this is how the `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` elements are tied together. Think of it as an id.

If you want to add a description to the servlet you can use the [`description`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1013555) element. You can also use comments.

Answer (score 1):

No, because that's what joins them together.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not valid. The `<servlet-name>...</servlet-name>` in both the `<servlet>...</servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>...</servlet-mapping>` tags must be the same as it binds the mapping to that particular servlet.

Keeping both different throws error whilst server start itself.

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servlets.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Error on server startup as the container cannot find any servlet entry whose servlet-name is HelloWorld1:**

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [Sample] : There is no web component by the name of HelloWorld1 here.. Please see server.log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that.

Because the servlet name that you define in section you define the URL Pattern with acts as an identifier to the servlet name that is used to map it with the class